# How to execute emulator commands via appium

Tags: android, testing, cmd, automated-tests, appium

I want to execute emulator commands via appium for automated Android tests.

adb shell commands can be executed easily for example like this ->

```java
driver.executeScript("mobile: shell", ImmutableMap.of("command", "dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus'"))
```

Is there any way to execute following command "adb emu network delay gprs"

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax would be:

```
Map<String, Object> argv = new HashMap<>();
argv.put("command", "dumpsys ");
argv.put("args", Lists.newArrayList("window", "windows", "|", "grep", "-E", "'mCurrentFocus'"));
String result = driver.executeScript("mobile: shell", argv).toString();
```

Reference: [How To Execute Shell Commands On The Remote Device](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-shell/#mobile-shell)

By the way, there are [Appium SeeTest Extensions](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Additional+Commands) which provide simplified syntax for running commands, like:

```
driver.executeScript("seetest:client.run(\"adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus'\")");
```